# Java - Most optimal way to poll for timeout

Tags: java

I have code such that:

```
while(isResponseArrived)
   Thread.yield();
```

But what I'd really like to do is something like this:

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeInMilliseconds();

while(isResponseArrived)
{
   if(isTimeoutReached(startTime))
       throw new TimeOutExcepton(); 
   Thread.yield();
}
```

I'm not yet sure about throwing an exception or not (it's not important for this question), but what I'd like to know is how to make it as performant as possible, so I'm not chugging away on the processor. In other words how can I make isTimeoutReached(long startTime) as performance friendly as possible.

I tested:

```
for(int x=0; x<99999999; x++)
    System.nanoTime();
```

versus

```
for(int x=0; x<99999999; x++)
    System.currentTimeInMilliseconds();
```

And the difference was minimal, less than 10% in terms of time to complete

I also look at using Thread.sleep(), but I really want the user to be notified as quickly as possible if there's an update and the processor is just waiting. Thread.yield() doesn't get the processor churning, it's just a NOP, giving anyone else processor priority, until it's good to go.

Anyways, what's the best way to test for a timeout without throttling the CPU? Is this the right method?

Comment: How do you set `isResponseArrived=true`? If it is set by a network response, the most optimal way will be reading an input channel with timeout.

Comment: I can't because once a networked channel is open, it stays open until I close it. It's not like an html call where the network is opened and closed right away, in this case the connection is always open, much more like an ssh connection. But what I want to do is limit the time any one command can take.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would be more efficient to use wait / notify

```
boolean arrived;

public synchronized void waitForResponse(long timeout) throws InterruptedException, TimeoutException {
    long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis() + timeout;
    while (!arrived) {
        long delay = System.currentTimeMillis() - t0;
        if (delay < 0) {
            throw new TimeoutException();
        }
        wait(delay);
    }
}

public synchronized void responseArrived() {
    arrived = true;
    notifyAll();
}
```

Comment: It may fail sometimes (from the documentation of wait()) : "_A thread can also wake up without being notified, interrupted, or timing out [...] In other words, waits should always occur in loop_"

Comment: correct, it's just an idea, not a production code. There an example how do this right in Thread.join(long millis)

Comment: The other problem is that you're going to forcing each loop to be whatever delay is. So for example, if you use 100ms, the smallest increment of time is 100ms.

Comment: Loop is just a protection against spurious wakeups (see Object.wait API). In real life there is no loop, waitForResponse blocks on wait, gets a signal when response arrives or times out.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience timeout are arbitarily chosen as as such as not time critical.  If I choose a timeout of 1000 ms and it takes 1001 ms instead the impact should be trivial.  For implementing timesout I suggest making the implementation as simple as possible.

You can implement Timeouts with a ScheduledExecutorService e.g.

```
final ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

public void addTimeoutForTask(final Future future, int timeOutMS) {
    ses.schedule(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            future.cancel(true);
        }
    }, timeOutMS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

If you are performing some non-blocking operation and you want this to timeout you can do.

```
interface TimedPoller {
    public void poll();

    /**
     * @return is it now closed.
     */
    public boolean checkTimeout(long nowNS);
}

private final Set<TimedPoller> timedPollers = new LinkedHashSet<>();
private volatile TimedPoller[] timedPollersArray = {};

public void add(TimedPoller timedPoller) {
    synchronized (timedPollers) {
        long nowNS = System.nanoTime();
        if (!timedPoller.checkTimeout(nowNS) && timedPollers.add(timedPoller))
            timedPollersArray = timedPollers.toArray(new TimedPoller[timedPollers.size());
    }
}

public void remove(TimedPoller timedPoller) {
    synchronized (timedPollers) {
        if (timedPollers.remove(timedPoller))
            timedPollersArray = timedPollers.toArray(new TimedPoller[timedPollers.size());
    }
}

private volatile boolean running = true;

public void run() {
    while (running) {
        // check the timeout for every 1000 polls.
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i += timedPollersArray.length) {
            TimedPoller[] pollers = timedPollersArray;
            for (TimedPoller poller : pollers) {
                poller.poll();
            }
        }
        long nowNS = System.nanoTime();
        TimedPoller[] pollers = timedPollersArray;
        for (TimedPoller poller : pollers) {
            if (poller.checkTimeout(nowNS))
                remove(poller);
        }
    }
}
```

Either you give up the CPU or you don't.  If you give up the CPU, other threads can run but you will get a delay before you can run again.  Or you don't give up the CPU which improves your response time, but another thread cannot run.

It appears you want to be able to let other things run, without the cost of giving up the CPU.  This is not trivial but can give you some of the benefits of both if done correctly (or worst of both if not done efficiently)

What you can do is implement your own threading logic provided you have lots of small tasks, e.g. say you want to poll ten things you can use just one CPU.

Comment: I don't mind giving up the CPU at all, what I'm afraid of is that the System.currrentTimeInMilliseconds() will bring the CPU to 100% if no other threads take it's place. So in fact I want teh other, I don't want to throttle the CPU checking to see if a timeout has occured.

Comment: Sorry I mis-read the question. I assumed you want to poll some IO as well.

Comment: I have updated my answer for just doing timeouts, or performing a non-blocking operation with a timeout.

Comment: I hate to say this, but your solution seems pretty complex for what is really a check every x polls (if I'm reading it right). I guess I'm not really seeing an advantage to what I had before in terms of possible CPU usage...

Comment: The first solution is the simplest and the one I would use.  If you have wait busy and you want to minimise how often you check timeouts as they don't need to be micro-second accurate, you can use the second option.

Comment: Why did you pick wait over sleep in this situation? I understand they are very similar but with subtle differences. My understanding is that wait will continue to execute if the processor has nothing to do versus sleep which says don't even try until at least this amount of time. So wouldn't wait consume the processor with time tests?

Comment: I assume you are talking about Evgeniy's solution but it appears to me this is done so that notifyAll() can wake it early.  wait is implemented by the OS at it's core and doesn't use any more CPU.

Comment: Yes, I just realized that after I posted the comment. That's why it's not always a good thing to be coding until 5am ;)